# How to determine the source of change of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, collections

I have the scenario where two `ObservableCollection` listen to changes among each other by subsribing to each other's `CollectionChanged` event. The goal is to keep both collections in sync.

How do I distinguish between

- External changes from a third person, i.e. because of some code that changes (add, remove, ...) one of the collections, and
- "internal changes" that take place because of the sync process (i.e. changes to one of the collections in order to keep up with the synchronization).

If I do not differentiate between those two? I thought of temporally the sync process. However, this will prevent me from being notified about external changes during syncronization (multi-threading). So I guess it all breaks down to the question where the change originated.

Comment: multi-threading? ObservableCollection should not be modified from outside the GUI thread http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are not averse to extending ObservableCollection class, you can do something like this:

```
public class SynchronizingCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    // the second, synchroniozed collection
    SynchronizingCollection<T> _synchronizedCollection;
    // field used to determine if the synchronization is already in progress
    bool _isSynchronizing = false;

    // Methods AddRange, RemoveItems, ReplaceAll, ClearAll
    // prevent CollectionChanged event from being rised unnecessarily
    // and allow for adding/clearing/replacing items in bulk
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, (IList)range.ToList()));
    }

    public void ReplaceAll(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        this.Items.Clear();
        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void RemoveItems(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {

        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Remove(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, (IList)range.ToList()));
    }

    public void ClearAll()
    {
        IList old = this.Items.ToList();
        base.Items.Clear();
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, old));
    }

    // assigning the second collection as synchronized
    public void SetSynchronizedCollection(SynchronizingCollection<T> synchronized)
    {
        this._synchronizedCollection = synchronized;
        this._synchronizedCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_synchronized_CollectionChanged);
        this.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(this_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void this_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isSynchronizing || _synchronizedCollection==null) return;
        _isSynchronizing = true;

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                _synchronizedCollection.AddRange(e.NewItems.OfType<T>());
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                // implement...
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                _synchronizedCollection.RemoveItems(e.OldItems.OfType<T>());
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                // implement...
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                _synchronizedCollection.ReplaceAll(this.Items);
                break;
        }

        _isSynchronizing = false;
    }

    void _synchronized_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isSynchronizing) return;
        _isSynchronizing = true;


        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                this.AddRange(e.NewItems.OfType<T>());
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                // implement...
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                this.RemoveItems(e.OldItems.OfType<T>());
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                // implement...
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                this.ReplaceAll(_synchronizedCollection.Items);
                break;
        }

        _isSynchronizing = false;
    }
}
```

using the code:

```
            SynchronizingCollection<string> c1 = new SynchronizingCollection<string>();
            SynchronizingCollection<string> c2 = new SynchronizingCollection<string>();

            c1.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(c1_CollectionChanged);
            c2.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(c2_CollectionChanged);
            c1.SetSynchronizedCollection(c2);

            c1.AddRange(new string[] { "d", "s" });
            c1.ClearAll();
            c1.Add("a");
            c1.Add("b");
            c1.Add("c");
            c1.Add("d");

            c2.Remove("c");

            List<string> l = new List<string> { "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5" };

            c2.AddRange(l);
            c1.RemoveItems(new string[] { "x2", "b" });
            c2.ReplaceAll(l);
//....

    void c1_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Action + " Collection 1 changed");
    }
    void c2_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Action + " Collection 2 changed");
    }
```